# Applescript error when trying to make excel paste unformatted text

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I am following these instructions: http://blog.mackerron.com/2009/05/19/paste-unformatted-keyboard-shortcut-office-2008-mac/
Worked fine in Word. But when i paste the code below into Applescript and save it to `/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Excel Script Menu Items`, I get this error `Syntax Error: Expected end of line, etc. but found “text”.`

```
try
  set theClip to Unicode text of (the clipboard as record)
  tell application "Microsoft Excel" to tell selection to type text text theClip
end try
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set theClip to the clipboard as text

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    set value of active cell to theClip
end tell
```

or this:

```
set theClip to the clipboard as text

tell application "Microsoft Excel" to activate
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel"
    keystroke theClip
end tell
```

Drag the script here:

```
tell application "Finder" to open (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Application Support:Microsoft:Office:Excel Script Menu Items:"
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't give an error when saving - and it works when excel is open and i press "Run" in the AppleScript editor - however it does not create the "Paste unformatted" option in the edit menu, and the shortcut (Apple+Alt+Shift+V) does not work. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Nope. The edit version does not create the "Paste unformatted" option nor does it enable the shortcut. And now each letter is "typed" after the other.

Comment: Either of those two suggestions should produce the same result as the "Paste unformatted" option. If not, please provide an example so I can help find a better solution.

Comment: The first suggestion produces the same result when i press "run" in the AppleScript Editor – but i can't activate/run it from Excel (not through the edit-menu nor through the shortcut).

Comment: Try installing it in the folder above.

Answer (score 0):

```
to type text text
```

Maybe you should to rename your variable text ?

Comment: ... but rename the variable to what? I am quite new to Applescript

Comment: Rename it to what you want, like "mytext" or something else. A lot of compiler/interpreter are not clever enough to make the distinction between an argument, a keyword and a variable.

Comment: This just gives me a new syntax error: `Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier.`
I think that Excel might use different functions than Word. Something like `set value of active cell` instead of `tell selection to type text`. etc.